# Convert List to Matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have the lists in matrix form, as shown in the screenshot fig.2 below. I would like to convert it to pure matrix like fig.1

Edited:
For example:

```
 (\!\(\*
TagBox[GridBox[{
  {
   RowBox[{"{", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "2", ",", "3"}], "}"}]},
  {
  RowBox[{"{", 
      RowBox[{"4", ",", "5", ",", "6"}], "}"}]},
        {
           RowBox[{"{", 
         RowBox[{"7", ",", "8", ",", "9"}], "}"}]}
        },
        GridBoxAlignment->{
  "Columns" -> {{Center}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
   "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}},
     GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {
         Offset[0.27999999999999997`], {
     Offset[0.5599999999999999]}, 
       Offset[0.27999999999999997`]}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, "Rows" 
  -> {
     Offset[0.2], {
   Offset[0.4]}, 
   Offset[0.2]}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}}],
    Column]\))
```

Fig.1
[image: Figure 1]

Fig.2
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Remove `MatrixForm` from fig 2, and just do    `mat = {list1,list2,....,listn}` should do it. But it is better to post the plain text Mathematica code you used to generate this.

Comment: Without something other users can copy to their *Mathematica* session, we can't help you.

Comment: I edited the question, thanks!

Comment: As already suggested, just remove `MatrixForm` from the code that created your expression in the question.  If, however, all you have is that expression, copy it into an `In` line and execute it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

(mat = RandomInteger[200, {3, 3}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Note that the [`MatrixForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixForm.html) wrapper is isolated from the definition of the matrix `mat` by the parentheses. This facilitates subsequent calculations with the matrix.

```
Tr@mat === Simplify@Total@Eigenvalues@mat

(* True *)
```

Comment: Your comment on the parentheses `( )` above has been very useful in many calculations of mine. Thanks.